# Using Taxonomy in drupal

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I need to create a custom form with a vendor dropdown ("Vendor A", "Vendor B") and a list box with multiple options belongs to selected vendor. Once a user select Vendor from dropdown, list box will be populated options related to this vendor. To do it in drupal 8, i created taxonomy vocabulary "vendors" and "vendorA_options", "vendorB_options" vocabulary to save vendor related options. Vendors will be max 5-8.

Is this the right way to do this in drupal 8 or i should add custom tables for it?

Thanks in advance.